# JqueryAjax and php logic

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hey guys im with a problem getting a value from php. I know we have a lot of problems with this kind of issues, but i need help.

This is my javascript

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".loading_bg").hide();
});

$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $(".loading_bg").fadeIn("slow");
});

function validate_user() {

            //We get data input
            var username = $('.username').val();
            var password = $('.password').val();

            //We create a datastring ex: functions.php?function=validate_user&username=username&password=password
            var datastring = 'function=validate_user' + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password; 

            //The json Ajax Request
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: '@loginAPI/functions.php',
                data: datastring,
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    $(".loading_bg").fadeOut("slow");
                },
                error: function(xhr, status){
                    console.log(status);
                }

            });
            return false;

        }
```

and this is my php

```
<?php
require_once('../@configs/db_connect.php');
//Lets send our data back to index
if(isset($_POST['function'])) {
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    echo login::validate_user($user, $password);   
}


class login {

    static function validate_user($username, $password) {


        //Call a new default connection
        $db = db::connect();

        //Prepare our sql
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Accounts WHERE username = :username AND password = :password");

        //Bind our values to the SQL statement
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        //Get number of affected rows
        $results = $stmt->rowCount();

        //If to check if we can find any row with username and password
        if($results === 1) {
            //return json_encode("valid account");
        } else {
            return json_encode($username);
        }

    }

}
?>
```

When i do the request im getting a undifned error from my var, i dont know how to fix it, can someone help me, if possible.

I think its something with my `$_POST`.. because if run the php with `login::validate_user("teste","teste);` i can get the json result..

Comment: Instead of a string, try using an object: `data: { username: username, password: password, function: 'validate_user' },` Maybe that will work better.

Comment: `trim($password);`  and `trim(user);` might help in case whitespace is getting caught up in there. You know to clean up and escape the ` POST ` vars before using them I am sure.

Comment: What does ` echo  isset($_POST['function']); `  return as an echo - 1 or 0 / -1?  Likewise `echo "User: " .  $user . " PW: " . $password;` what do you get - just before ` echo login::....`?

Comment: Client-side, `console.log(datastring)` .... is it what you expect?

Comment: @Rasclatt Hi, i did what u advise, but still the same :C

Comment: @Steve i had $.trim() but i remove just to debug stuff, the isset($_POST['function']) allows me to know if the ajax request was made with the function = validate_user in my data string, i tried to do an echo json_encode("hello"); inside the isset() but this time i got a parserro

Comment: @Roamer its not datastring but im expecting to get results from sucess: function(result)

Comment: Surely if ajax uses post then the vars will be in the ` $_POST ` array? try a simple echo "Hello"; inside the isset();  How about comment out the isset() for quick testing? and echo $user and $password as comment above.

Comment: @Steve its fixed :D Thank you too !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything else is fine, you are not passing data correctly to ajax call. You are making query string but you have to pass JSON object if you want to capture it in $_POST in php and can append to url if you want to capture in $_GET array. I have corrected your function in both ways below:

```
function validate_user() {

    //We get data input
    var username = $('.username').val();
    var password = $('.password').val();

    //We create a datastring ex: functions.php?function=validate_user&username=username&password=password
    var datastring = { 'function': 'validate_user', 'username': username, 'password': password }

    //The json Ajax Request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@loginAPI/functions.php',
        data: datastring,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $(".loading_bg").fadeOut("slow");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status){
            console.log(status);
        }

    });
    return false;

}
```

When you want to capture data in $_GET at server side

```
function validate_user() {
    //We get data input
    var username = $('.username').val();
    var password = $('.password').val();

    //We create a datastring ex: functions.php?function=validate_user&username=username&password=password
    var datastring = 'function=validate_user' + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password; 

    //The json Ajax Request
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '@loginAPI/functions.php?' + datastring,
        data: {},
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $(".loading_bg").fadeOut("slow");
        },
        error: function(xhr, status){
            console.log(status);
        }

    });
    return false;

}
```

Here is PHP Code

```
<?php
require_once('../@configs/db_connect.php');
//Lets send our data back to index
if(isset($_GET['function'])) {
    $user = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    echo login::validate_user($user, $password);   
}
.... // Remaining Class will come here
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, im trying the second one, where u capture the data with $_GET, and i tried the other one too, but im getting undefined

Comment: This may be a good suggestion but your `datastring` is not JSON. It is a javascript plain object, written in  "object literal" syntax.

Comment: Verify if input fields are having correct classes? Can you give me HTML of form ?

Comment: omg... i didnt add the classes to the html input forms.. i lost hours checking the ajax request.. i fixed already.. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry to bother all of you, the real problem its my form input feilds.. i forgot to set a class... Thank you all, and once again, im sorry to make you lose time with such a silly problem.

Comment: So my `console.log(datastring)` wasn't such a daft suggestion after all!