# I can upload files with jquery ajax and php, some explaination and modification required

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form-data

I have read this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData

Still can't understand why is formdata(frm) is empty in code. `console.log(frm);` returns "FormData{}" empty. Why?

file_form.php =>

```
<title>Upload File</title>
<div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
<img id="my_image1" src="" />
<img id="my_image2" src="" />

<form id="uploadForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image1" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="uploadForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image2" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadForm1").on('submit', (function (e) {
            frm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            console.log(frm);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload_script1.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: frm,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    var JsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
                    $("#targetLayer").html(response);

                    var fl1 = "uploads/" + JsonObject.image1;
                    $("#my_image1").attr("src", fl1).height(100).width(100);
                }
            });
        }));

        $("#uploadForm2").on('submit', (function (e) {
            frm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload_script2.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: frm,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    var JsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
                    $("#targetLayer").html(response);

                    var fl2 = "uploads/" + JsonObject.image2;
                    $("#my_image2").attr("src", fl2).height(100).width(100);
                }
            });
        }));


    });
</script>
```

upload_script1.php =>

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/file-upload/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image1']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

    $image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
    $images["image1"] = $image1;
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

upload_script2.php =>

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/file-upload/uploads/';
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image2']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    $image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
    $images["image2"] = $image2;
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

1. Can anyone rewrite the two `$.ajax()` code to one `$.ajax()` code making the code shorter? Re-write the html and php code if necessary.

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a valid enctype is required `enctype= multipart/form-data` if you're not already using one. This example being for pure PHP of course.

Comment: Can you post example code?

Comment: they're already in the links you posted. if none of them worked for you, then I suggest you look into "why" they're not working and checking for errors. Make sure the folder you're wanting to upload to, has the proper permissions to write to it. I can't say anything more that's already been said in those links you left in your question.

Comment: Are you telling me to add this? `<form method="POST" action="upload_script.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: for the most part, yes.

Comment: I have edited original question. Now what to do?

Comment: I have edited the original question.

Comment: `Still can't understand why is formdata(frm) is empty in code. console.log(frm); returns "FormData{}" empty. Why?` You cannot read `FormData` data (it would using `get(), getAll()` methods but only Opera supports it or chrome under flag) , only public method is `append()`.  As a side note, your code has typo here: `$("#uploadForm1").on('submit',(function(e) {`

Comment: why you aren't using serialize() ??

Comment: @asfandahmed1, Are you telling me to use `data:  $(this)[0].serialize(),` ?

Comment: @asfandahmed1 `serialize()` doesn't include input of type file, how could it do?

Comment: @shibly yes you can do it using serialize() instead of FormData.

Comment: if thats the case then try data:new FormData(this);

Comment: Not sure if this might help but seemed similar regarding Ajax and POST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33965525/jqueryajax-and-php-logic?noredirect=1#comment55689448_33965525

Comment: You can achieve an AJAX like uploading effect by using an iframe. You can get excellent browser support about as far back as IE goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modifid only the javascript part.

My example is...

```
<title>Upload File</title>
<div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
<img id="my_image1" src=""/>
<img id="my_image2" src=""/>

<form id="uploadForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image1" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="uploadForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image2" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function fetch( type ) {

    var typeMap = {
        form1: { formId: 'uploadForm1', url: 'upload_script1.php', flKey: 'image1', imgId: 'my_image1' },
        form2: { formId: 'uploadForm2', url: 'upload_script2.php', flKey: 'image2', imgId: 'my_image2' }
    };

    var info = typeMap[ type ];
    if( ! info ) return console.error('no type: ' + type );

    $("#"+info.formId).on('submit',(function(e) {

        frm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        console.log(frm);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: info.url,
            type: "POST",
            data:  frm,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(response){                
                var JsonObject = JSON.parse(response);              
                $("#targetLayer").html(response);

                var fl = "uploads/" + JsonObject[ info.flKey ];
                $("#"+info.imgId).attr("src",fl).height(100).width(100);
            }           
       });
    }));
}

$(document).ready(function (e) {    
    fetch( 'form1' );
    fetch( 'form2' );
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why `console.log(frm);` returns empty formdata?

Comment: @shibly This is by design, surely to not have to handle other security hole, which one, i don't know... But it doesn't mean your FormData is empty, you have to get it server side

Comment: @A.Wolff, If i write `echo json_encode($_POST);` in upload_script1.php, i get `[]` for `$("#targetLayer").html(response);`

Comment: @shibly I'm not a PHP guru but i don't see any POST data passed to server, only `$_FILES`. Now if you try `echo json_encode($_FILES);` i'm really not sure what to expect, encoding a data file to JSON, hmm...

Comment: @A.Wolff, I get values for `echo json_encode($_FILES);`, but could not get anything for `echo json_encode($_POST);` , why is this? Isn't `data:  frm,` supposed to be in `$_POST`?

Comment: @shibly like said, im not a php guy, so not sure what to expect here, sorry

Answer (score 4):

Your `FormData` object is probably showing as empty because your browser doesn't support [iterators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Check out the methods [compatibility table at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility). Internally, the console will probably try to use the iterator exposed by the `entries` method to enumerate the properties.

I get the same result in Chromium 45.

---

As for simplifying the code, you can merge both functions and PHP scripts by parameterizing them.

```
function createFormHandler($form, url, $image) {
  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    var frm = new FormData($form[0]);
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: frm,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(response) {                
        var JsonObject = JSON.parse(response);              
        $("#targetLayer").html(response);
        var src = "uploads/" + JsonObject.image1;
        $image.attr("src", src).height(100).width(100);
      }           
    });
  });
}

createFormHandler($('#uploadForm1'), 'upload_script.php?id=1', $('#my_image1'));
createFormHandler($('#uploadForm2'), 'upload_script.php?id=2', $('#my_image2'));
```

Now the numeric id of each form is represented as a URL parameter, rather than having to be a separate script. You can merge both PHP files and use a single `upload_script.php` instead.

```
<?php
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/file-upload/uploads/';
  $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);

  $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
  $images["image" . $id] = $image;
  echo json_encode($images);
?>
```

This lets you normalize the input names too.

```
<form id="uploadForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="image" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="uploadForm2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="image" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: How can i get the value of `data: frm,` in upload_script.php? Does $_POST contain the value of `data: frm,` ?

Comment: Yeah, the input names in your form correspond with entries in the `$_POST` array — files however are special values and will end up in `$_FILES` instead.

Comment: `var src = "uploads/" + JsonObject.image1;` , you are using `image1` here. Image2 will not appear.

Comment: Oops. Missed that. It just needs to be parameterized in the same way the other fields are and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

```
I think it will minimize your code

<title>Upload File</title>
<div id="targetLayer">No Image</div>
<img id="my_image1" src="" />
<img id="my_image2" src="" />

<form id="uploadForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image1" type="file" />
    <input name="image2" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function (e) {
        $("#uploadForm1").on('submit', (function (e) {
            frm = new FormData($(this)[0]);
            console.log(frm);
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "upload_script1.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: frm,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,

                success: function (response) {
                    var JsonObject = JSON.parse(response);
                    $("#targetLayer").html(response);

                    var fl1 = "uploads/" + JsonObject.image1;
                    $("#my_image1").attr("src", fl1).height(100).width(100);
                     $("#my_image2").attr("src", fl2).height(100).width(100);
                }
            });
        }));



    });
</script>

upload_script1.php =>

<?php
    $uploaddir = '/var/www/html/file-upload/uploads/';

    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image1']['name']);
     $uploadfile2 = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['image2']['name']);     
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile2);
    $image1 = $_FILES['image1']['name'];
    $image2 = $_FILES['image2']['name'];
    $images["image1"] = $image1;
     $images["image2"] = $image2;
    echo json_encode($images);
?>
```